# Hive jdbc set memory params

Tags: java, sql, hadoop, jdbc, hive

Hive has some parameters which decide how much memory it uses in map/reduce :

```
set mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb = 10096 ; 
set mapreduce.map.memory.mb = 10096 ;
```

so usually when I use hive shell for a big query I run something like

```
hive -e "set mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb = 10096 ; set mapreduce.map.memory.mb = 10096 ; select * from table"
```

But when I use jdbc with hive from java, I cant seem to find a way to increase memory for large queries.
I run something like this:

```
String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"; 
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://machines/hiveDB");
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

But JDBC blocks running multiple queries in a single query so I cant do what I did in hive shell, and I dont see another way to do it, so right now I just cant run queries which are too big.
Anyone has any idea? I thought about running multiple statements but nothing guarantees they will run on the same machine.

TL;DR would like to set hive parameters in java jdbc using the hivedriver for large queries and cant figure a way.

Comment: Did you try sending them as three separate statements, one after another, on the same connection?

Comment: But how would I know they will execute on the same machine? I mentioned in the question I thought about it. but see no reason for it to work.

Comment: Since you are using the same connection, the commands will be sent to the same *session*. In fact, that's exactly what the hive CLI is doing.